# Backup/Copying external Hard drive to Time Capsule

Tags: backup, time-capsule

I'm trying to copy everything on an External hard drive to my Time Capsule. I figured plugging it into the Time Capsule would be quickest. But if I start the copy on my Macbook (wireless) will the data go through the macbook and be much slower than just copying directly over USB?

Airport Utility lets you archive the Time Capsule to the external HDD, but I want to do the opposite.

Also if I start the copy on my Macbook I'm guessing it will stop copying when I close the macbook?